# Why would this not work in IE10, but works in IE7

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have a form that I want to break up into three different sections each with a "next" and "back" button to show the next or previous section respectively. For the most part it is working how i want, except in IE10+. it works in Firefox, Chrome, and IE7 (not sure about 8 and 9).

the part of the code that isn't working is:

```
$("#sell_body2").hide();
$("#sell_body3").hide();


$('#sell_next1').click(function () {
    $("#sell_body1").fadeOut(250);
    setTimeout('$("#sell_body2").fadeIn(250)', 250);
});
$('#sell_next2').click(function () {
    $("#sell_body2").fadeOut(250);
    setTimeout('$("#sell_body3").fadeIn(250)', 250);
});
$('#sell_back2').click(function () {
    $("#sell_body2").fadeOut(250);
    setTimeout('$("#sell_body1").fadeIn(250)', 250);
});
$('#sell_back3').click(function () {
    $("#sell_body3").fadeOut(250);
    setTimeout('$("#sell_body2").fadeIn(250)', 250);
});
```

here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/PHYL2/
in JSFiddle it works exactly how i want, but in IE10+ when i click the first "next" button, the current section fades out (like it should) but the next never fades in

NOTE: please excuse the horrid looks, i have only posted the code affected by the problem

Comment: Compatibility mode? Ironically, nothing works in compatibility mode.

Comment: i may have to remove the "+" from IE10+. does anyone else get the same result? if not then i will have to look at my specific browser more carefully

Comment: Works for me in IE10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is it's a problem deciphering / evaluating your timeout execution strings.

Rather than setting a timeout, why not just use the `fadeOut` [*complete* callback](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/#fadeOut-duration-complete), eg

```
$('#sell_next1').on('click', function() {
    $('#sell_body1').fadeOut(250, function() {
        $('#sell_body2').fadeIn(250);
    });
});
```

I'd actually go a step further and make this much more generic.

Say your trigger elements look something like this...

```
<button id="sell_next1" class="next-btn"
    data-target-out="#sell_body1" data-target-in="#sell_body2">Hide body1, show body2</button>
```

Then you can write one generic handler...

```
$('.next-btn').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this),
        in = $this.data('target-in'),
        out = $this.data('target-out');
    $(out).fadeOut(250, function() {
        $(in).fadeIn(250);
    });            
});
```

Comment: I originally had it has that, however, it seemed that the next one would start to fade in slightly before the first one was gone making it unsightly, i may have had it setup wrong though. If i can't figure this out I may go back and try that way again

Comment: @CumminUp07 For that problem try looking into `.stop`. (http://api.jquery.com/stop/). The second parameter tells it to "jump to end" or finish the animation. When one animation starts you can tell the other ones to stop.

Comment: i knew there had to be a simpler way. this works exactly how i want in all the browsers that i care about and makes my code much cleaner